# Persisting object with ManyToMany relation is not visible from inverse side

Tags: java

in my code, I have an `Employee` and `Task` entities, related with ManyToMany relation. When creating new `Employee` object, I can assign him to existing tasks with `empToBePersisted.getTasks().add(existingTask)`. However, when I persist it, the relation is persisted in databse but only seen from the `Employee` side. The `Task` sees it after restarting the app. How can I make it visible immediately after persisting?

Comment: please post the relevant code. Since you tagged the question with java-ee - are you persisting from an EJB?

Comment: I think I hastened a bit with placing it in java-ee as for now I'm using it only in console application where there is no JTA. I believe that The Apprentice answer is enough to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Described behaviour is normal. You need to handle both sides when working with bidirectional associations.

> Bidirectional relationships between managed entities will be persisted
>   based on references held by the owning side of the relationship. It is
>   the developer’s responsibility to keep the in-memory references held
>   on the owning side and those held on the inverse side consistent with
>   each other when they change.

In this case, you will need to call existingTask.setEmployee(empToBePersisted) manually.

You can also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630553/2874662) for more details.