# EntityManager merge is not working while updating OneToMany Side

Tags: java, entity, jpa-2.0

I have two entities with bidirectional **OneToMany** relationship . eg

**Employee.java**

```
package com.jpademo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Employee
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Emp_Id_Gen", sequenceName = "EMP_ID_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Emp_Id_Gen")
    private Integer employeeId;

    private String Name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Department department;

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

**Department.java**

```
package com.jpademo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Department
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Dept_Id_Gen", sequenceName = "DEPT_ID_SEQ_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Dept_Id_Gen")
    private Integer deptId;

    private String deptName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Integer getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }

    public void setDeptId(Integer deptId) {
        this.deptId = deptId;
    }

    public String getDeptName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setDeptName(String deptName) {
        this.deptName = deptName;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeDAO.java**

```
package com.jpademo.dao;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.jpademo.entities.Department;
import com.jpademo.entities.Employee;

@Stateless(name = "employeeDAO")
@LocalBean
public class EmployeeDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPA2Pratice")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void saveEmployee() {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setName("Mukesh Saini");
        Department dept = new Department();
        dept.setDeptName("Physics");
        emp.setDepartment(dept);
        em.persist(emp);
    }

    public void addEmployeeToDepartment() {
        TypedQuery<Department> departmentQuery = em
                .createQuery(
                        "SELECT dept FROM Department dept WHERE dept.deptId = :departmentId",
                        Department.class);
        departmentQuery.setParameter("departmentId", 1);
        Department dept = departmentQuery.getSingleResult();
        // Employee already in department
        List<Employee> currentEmpinDept = dept.getEmployees();

        // Employee that need to be add in department
        TypedQuery<Employee> employeeQuery = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT emp FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.employeeId IN :empIds",
                Employee.class);
        employeeQuery.setParameter("empIds", Arrays.asList(2, 3));
        List<Employee> employees = employeeQuery.getResultList();
        currentEmpinDept.addAll(employees);
        dept.setEmployees(currentEmpinDept);
        em.merge(dept); // this does not update employee department

    }



}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPA2Pratice">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MySQLDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In method **addEmployeeToDepartment** in EmployeeDAO **em.merge(dept)** is not updating the Employee Department, what am I doing wrong here. Or **Does cascade works from Parent to child only ?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about a **merge** here, you just need to update both sides of the relationship.   The employee objects returned from your query are already managed/attached.

But according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630439/jpa-question-on-impedance-mismatch-in-onetomany-relations) and [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#Do_I_have_to_maintain_both_sides_of_a_bi-directional_relationship.3F) it's not enough to simply set the new list of Employee objects on the parent Department object.  You have to update the reference to the Department on each child Employee as well.

So you could just add:

```
    // ...
    List<Employee> employees = employeeQuery.getResultList();

    // NEW:  Update owning side     
    for (Employee e : employees) {
        e.setDepartment(dept);
    }
    currentEmpinDept.addAll(employees);
    dept.setEmployees(currentEmpinDept);

    //em.merge(dept);   - DON'T THINK THIS IS NEEDED
}
```

Comment: this is not what I am asking but thanks for your reply

Comment: Since I'm not sure what you were asking differently, I edited my answer to explain what I was saying more clearly.